# Spring MVC не видит view(.jps)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, eclipse, tomcat

Создал простое веб приложение, которое должно отобразить jsp страницу при переходе по ссылке http://localhost:8083/demo-spring/bye, но получаю ошибку 404

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cтруктура проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс ApplicationRunner:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var context = SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRunner.class, args);
    }
}
```

Так же есть application.yml

```
spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/
      suffix: .jsp

server:
  port: 8083
```

Ещё есть один котроллер

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping("/bye")
    public ModelAndView bye() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("greeting/bye");       
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Pom.xml проекта:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.0-M13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

В консоли никаких ошибок не вывелось.

Сначала думал, что ошибка в адресной строке, перепробовал много разных адресов, но ничего так и не получилось.
Пробовал запускать приложение не через embedded tomcat, а через приложение, но опять же ничего не получилось

Comment: У вас представления помимо того, что вложены в папку `greeting`, ещё и сама эта папка находится в папке `jpa`. Попробуйте добавить в путь ещё и `jpa` - либо в префикс в настроечном файле, либо в самом контроллере.

Comment: По замечанию Byb исправил путь в application.yml на  "prefix: /WEB-INF/jpa/", однако это всё равно не помогло:(